# Simulate the computing power required to apply a pre-trained model

Tags: simulation, time-complexity, estimation

I am very new to the field of machine learning and hope this question fits here.

Is there a way to generate an estimate of the computational effort required to classify a value using a previously trained machine learning model? Or to simulate the computational effort required?

I've already looked at some articles on this, but I'm not sure if I've understood it correctly.
Here, for example (https://www.kaggle.com/general/263127), the various complexities of the models are described with mathematical models. But how could I estimate how much time it would take to simulate the models on a certain processor?

Comment: Why don't you try the model on that specific computer and see exactly how much computational power it takes?

Comment: I want to be able to calculate the potentially needed time to do a classification with a set amount of parameters and computational power. I can not try it out because later I also want to calculate an estimation with multiple devices running the same classification.